# Is there a way to pass the cypress.io baseUrl env var into my package.json run scripts?

Tags: node.js, json, environment-variables, cypress

I want to be able to pass the `baseUrl` from the `cypress.json` file into the `scripts` of the `package.json` file for my cypress test project.  Is this possible?

I have been looking at the cypress documentation and stack overflow but I cannot find a solution that does not require adding another script to do something like `"get-base-url": "type cypress.json | jq -r .baseUrl"` and pass this script as an argument into the relevant `"test"` script (see below)

cypress.json file

```
{
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000/",
  //other key-value pairs
  }
}
```

package.json scripts section

```
{
//other settings
  "scripts": {
//other scripts
    "test": "start-server-and-test website:dev http://localhost:3000 cy:run",
  }, 
//other settings
}
```

I anticipated there would be an equivalent to `Cypress.config().baseUrl`, to get the value of the `baseUrl` in the json file.

Resulting in something similar to the following (sudo-code, doesnt work)

```
{
//other settings
  "scripts": {
  //other scripts
    "test": "start-server-and-test website:dev ${baseUrl} cy:run",
  }, 
//other settings
}
```

NB: I have not posted on Stack Overflow before, so I apologise if I have not given enough info and/or missed something in the rules.

Answer (score 0):

scripts capability is limited. You need a small script to receive baseUrl from cypress.json and pass it into the **start-server-and-test** package 
Let's say we create a script called **start-server-and-test.js** with the following code and put it under the **scripts** directory

```
const cypressConfig = require('../cypress.json') // line 1
const startServerAndTest = require('start-server-and-test') // line 2
const [startScript, testScript] = process.argv.slice(2) // line 3
startServerAndTest({  // line 4
  start: `npm ${startScript}`,
  url: cypressConfig.baseUrl,
  test: `npm ${testScript}`,
})
```

Here is how we use it in **package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node scripts/start-server-and-test.js website:dev cy:run",
  }, 
}
```

---

Short explanation:

- Line 1: read cypress.json and assign to cypressConfig which you can access baseUrl later by **cypressConfig.baseUrl**
- Line 3: retrieve arguments in the command-line which are **['website:dev', 'cy:run']**
- Line 4: Run the package with corresponding parameters

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, appreciated.  I am getting errors but will try to fix before posting further (doesnt seem to be able to locate the second part of the script `(node:9620) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: spawn npm website:dev ENOENT
    at notFoundError`

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to elaborate on Hung Tran's solution above for 2021:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
require("dotenv").config();

const startServerAndTest = require("start-server-and-test");
const [startScript, testScript] = process.argv.slice(2);

startServerAndTest.startAndTest({
  services: [{ start: `npm run ${startScript}`, url: process.env.CYPRESS_BASE_URL }],
  test: `npm run ${testScript}`,
});
```